# How to mount a WD500 gb external drive on ubuntu 13.10 running on trial through pen drive

Tags: mount, external-hdd

I have installed ubuntu 13.10 on my 16gb pen drive.

I launched Ubuntu by clicking 'try' and not installing it on my laptop.

I connected a newly purchased 500GB WD Elements External Drive. - It is not mounting.

When I clicked on d DISKS...  it is showing me the drive but I did not get the play button to mount it.

Please help me with the solution.
when I click the drive in DISKS it is showing:

```
MODEL WDC WD5000LMVW-11VEDS3 (01.01A01)
SIZE 500 GB (500,074,283,008 bytes)
Partioning MASTER BOOT RECORD
Serial number WD-WXB1A63F3949
Assessmment SMART is not supported
Device /dev/sdc
Contents Unallocated Space
```

Comment: did you try executing `sudo mount /dev/sdc /mnt`?

Answer (score 0):

follow below steps :
find device (50GB WD) device file i.e. /dev/sdx1 where x is a,b,c,d,...
type command in terminal

```
$ fdisk -l
```

(find your device mount path)
Now need to mount on directory

```
$ mount /dev/sdx1 /mnt
```

(here i want to mount my drive at /mnt But you can specified your location y replace it)
on successful it will mounted on /mnt.

AS you purchase new External Drive, it might be not formated OR made any partition table 
If it so Please launch GPated Software and make Partition table.

Hope it will help you

Comment: USE GPated by searching in dash home